# Is there a typeclass for all sequences in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm messing around with algebraic structures, and I find the `Numeric` typeclass very handy for well, representing numeric values.

So I can write my monoid instance this way:

```
implicit def add[A: Numeric] = new Monoid[A] {
  def mempty = implicitly[Numeric[A]].zero
  def mappend(a0: A, a1: A) = implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(a0, a1)
}
```

This looks like a dandy. But what can I do with sequences? I can't find a typeclass that does standard Scala collection sequences. I would like to write something like this:

```
def concat[A : SeqTC] = new Monoid[A] {
  def mempty = implicitly[SeqTC[A]].empty
  def mappend(a0: A, a1: A) = implicitly[SeqTC[A]].++(a0, a1)
}
```

Comment: Have a look at CanBuild and CanBuildFrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @TrustNoOne's comment, this is what I achieved to do. And it works great.

```
def concat[A, S[A] <: Seq[A]](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], A, S[A]]) = new Monoid[S[A]] {
  def mempty = bf().result()
  def mappend(a0: S[A], a1: S[A]) = bf.apply().++=(a0).++=(a1).result()
}
```